# Count number of shortest paths on a board

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a program that finds the number of shortest paths on a board that is nxn. This should use binary tree recursion. It takes two numbers representing the position of some square on the board, and returns the number of distinct shortest paths between the indicated square and the upper left corner. And you can only move up, down, left, or right.

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 . . . . . . . . .
1 . . . . . . . . .
2 . . . . . . . . .
3 . . . . . . . . .
4 . . . . . . x . .
5 . . . . . . . . .
6 . . . . . . . . .
```

In this case x is at row 4 col 6. The program should count the number of *shortest* paths. Obviously if x is on an edge then there is only one shortest path.

```
(check-expect (shortest 0 0) 0)
(check-expect (shortest 0 1) 1) 
(check-expect (shortest 1 0) 1) 
(check-expect (shortest 1 1) 2) 
(check-expect (shortest 1 2) 3) 
(check-expect (shortest 2 1) 3) 
(check-expect (shortest 2 2) 6) 
(check-expect (shortest 2 3) 10) 
(check-expect (shortest 2 7) 36) 
(check-expect (shortest 6 5) 462)
```

I believe I'm really close, but I'm having a problem in the else case:

```
(define (shortest x y)
  (cond
    [(= x y 0) 0]
    [(or (zero? y) (zero? x)) 1]
    [else (+ 1 (shortest (sub1 x) y)
               (shortest x (sub1 y)))]))
```

I thought there would be an if statement within the else, but I'm not sure what to test.

This should not have any helpers, lambdas, locals, etc.. and in ISL+. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell if you change the 4th line from

```
 [else (+ 1 (shortest (sub1 x) y)
```

to

```
 [else (+ (shortest (sub1 x) y)
```

the function should work as required.  So...

```
(define (shortest x y)
  (cond
    [(= x y 0) 0]
    [(or (zero? y) (zero? x)) 1]
    [else (+ (shortest (sub1 x) y)
             (shortest x (sub1 y)))]))
```

and no need for ifs in the else.